# Prometheus: no metric node_cpu

Tags: prometheus

I've setup Prometheus and node_exporter. All example graphs I've found utilize `node_cpu` but I don't have this metric present. The closest I've come is `node_cpu_seconds_total`. Am I missing something or is my version of Prometheus incompatible with these graphs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 0.16.0 version of the node exporter improved many key metrics to follow naming guidelines that arose since it was created, so `node_cpu_seconds_total` is the new name. Many dashboards etc. are still using the old names.